# How to check status of PostgreSQL server Mac OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql

How can I tell if my Postgresql server is running or not?

I'm getting this message:

```
[~/dev/working/sw] sudo bundle exec rake db:migrate 
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Update:

```
> which postgres
/usr/local/bin/postgres
> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/bin/postgres -l /usr/local/bin/postgres/server.log start
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/bin/postgres/postmaster.pid": Not a directory
```

Update 2:

```
>pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
server starting
sh: /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You should also look out for multiple versions of postgres on Mac OS/X. If you've installed postgres via homebrew then you can get the above error when your path is incorrectly setup - I just accidentally fudged my path and everything started using the system install of postgres which didn't work very well until I adjusted the path to use the brew install

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The simplest way to to check running processes:

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres
```

And look for a command that looks something like this (your version may not be 8.3):

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/8.3/bin/postgres -D /Library/PostgreSQL/8.3/data
```

To start the server, execute something like this:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/8.3/bin/pg_ctl start -D /Library/PostgreSQL/8.3/data -l postgres.log
```

Comment: ok and if i don't find anything like that, how do I start the server?

Comment: `pgrep postgres` also works. Or `ps auxwww | grep [p]ostgres` to prevent the `grep` from getting picked up.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: the `ps | grep` malpractice suggestion. `pgrep` is acceptable, barely. `pg_ctl status` is *great*. `ps auxwww | grep postgres` is going to match `grep postgres`, and `less /var/log/postgres/whatever`.

Comment: it should be noted that the database cluster directory `/Library/PostgreSQL/8.3/data` is arbitrarily created by the user via the `initdb` command. here is the [8.3 doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/creating-cluster.html)

Answer (score 81):

You can run the following command to determine if postgress is running:

```
$ pg_ctl status
```

You'll also want to set the `PGDATA` environment variable.

Here's what I have in my `~/.bashrc` file for postgres:

```
export PGDATA='/usr/local/var/postgres'
export PGHOST=localhost
alias start-pg='pg_ctl -l $PGDATA/server.log start'
alias stop-pg='pg_ctl stop -m fast'
alias show-pg-status='pg_ctl status'
alias restart-pg='pg_ctl reload'
```

To get them to take effect, remember to source it like so:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

Now, try it and you should get something like this:

```
$ show-pg-status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 11030)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/bin/postgres
```

Comment: Given your error message, I bet SamGoody's suggestion to run your initdb command will fix your "Connection refused" problem.  Once it's fixed, try my suggestions to get your postgres db server status.

Answer (score 38):

As of PostgreSQL 9.3, you can use the command `pg_isready` to determine the connection status of a PostgreSQL server.

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pg-isready.html):

> pg_isready returns 0 to the shell if the server is accepting connections normally, 1 if the server is rejecting connections (for example during startup), 2 if there was no response to the connection attempt, and 3 if no attempt was made (for example due to invalid parameters).

Comment: How do you check the same for psql before 9.3?

Answer (score 32):

You probably did not init postgres.

If you installed using HomeBrew, the init must be run before anything else becomes usable.

To see the instructions, run `brew info postgres`

```
# Create/Upgrade a Database
If this is your first install, create a database with:
     initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8

To have launchd start postgresql at login:
   ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents 
Then to load postgresql now:     
   launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist 
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Once you have run that, it should say something like:

> Success. You can now start the database server using:
>
> ```
> postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres or
> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start
> ```

If you are still having issues, check your firewall. If you use a good one like HandsOff! and it was configured to block traffic, then your page will not see the database.

Comment: `brew info postgresql` these days

Answer (score 14):

You can use brew to start/stop pgsql. I've following short cuts in my *~/.bashrc* file

```
alias start-pg='brew services start postgresql'
alias stop-pg='brew services stop postgresql'
alias restart-pg='brew services restart postgresql'
```

Comment: Question about `How to check status` not to start/stop pgsql!

Comment: you can try...
brew services list | grep postgres

Comment: Love those aliases!

Comment: brew services info postgresql will provide the info

Answer (score 13):

It depends on where your postgresql server is installed. You use the pg_ctl to manually start the server like below.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Comment: @Ramy You substituted *bin* for *var* in the path.

Comment: hmmm...ok. i thought i needed to check for where my install was. please see new update.

Comment: How did you install postgres? Did you run initdb after installing postgres?

Answer (score 6):

The `pg_ctl status` command suggested in other answers checks that the postmaster process exists and if so reports that it's running. That doesn't necessarily mean it is ready to accept connections or execute queries.

It is better to use another method like using `psql` to run a simple query and checking the exit code, e.g. `psql -c 'SELECT 1'`, or use `pg_isready` [to check the connection status](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-isready.html).

Comment: `psql -c "SELECT 1" -d {dbname} > /dev/null || postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres >postgres.log 2>&1 &` if you want to check and start postgres in one go (handy for automation scripts).