# psql: could not connect to server on Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, psql, postgresql-9.4

I installed PostgreSQL on Linux, how is indicated in [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/es/PostgreSql)

After installation I run the following commands:

```
# su - postgres
$ psql
```

And I got the following error:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I found I solutions, but for Mac

[Postgres could not connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory

How can I solve this issue in Linux?

Distribution details:

```
Distributor ID : Debian
Description    : Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release        : 8.7
Codename       : jessie

PostgreSQL     : 9.4
```

Comment: Is your environment set properly? What does `env | grep '^PG'` show?

Comment: Nothing, may it be the problem? How can I solved?

Comment: Please see this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html

Comment: Check if PostgreSQL service is running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975414/how-to-check-status-of-postgresql-server-mac-os-x

Comment: Yes, It is running.

Comment: You will find your answer in the related post I pasted above.

Comment: I followed the steps, but I continue getting the error...

Comment: What do you get for `pg_ctl status`? What is the value of the parameters `unix_socket_directories` and `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`? Is there a file `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` on your computer? What do you get if you `telnet localhost 5432`?

Comment: Sorry for the late late late time to response. I found that the problem is that PostgreSQL is not adding paths to enviromental variables when login to psql user.